# Watershed delineating

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, topology

I have generated a stream from my DEM. I also have a shapefile of the river which i am working on. I want to overlay the river on the generated stream from the DEM and check if i could see whether the river overlayed will fall on the streams generated and then could generated watershed.

But the challenge is that, since most of the streams generated are not connecting to the path where the river shapefile is overlayed, i am finding it difficult to an entire watershed for the river. Only subwatersheds can i generate. I want to find a way of connecting the gap/space between two streams which are capable of forming subwatershed where the river passes.

So i just want to know whether such procedure is feasible and if so how could it be done.

I have attached a picture of the generated stream and the river shapefile (red line) for attention[image: Stream generation and polyline shapefile of the river]

Comment: You have an ArcPy tag and not one for ArcGIS Desktop.  Are you looking for an ArcPy solution?  If so, then what does your code so far look like?

Comment: Which functions are you using to get to this result? Spatial Analyst-Hydrology tools, ArcHydro Tools, Whitebox or something else? A few things can be noted from your result though: 1. Fill Sinks have destroyed important parts of your DEM. 2. Your DEM seems to be way too small for your area of interest. 3. What resolution is your DEM? It seems unlikely that your river is so completely misinterpreted by the algorithm. This will need some manual adjustments. (Do you have bridges or roads or things like that, which could impact flow paths in a wrongful manner?) Please provide more info! :)

Comment: Yeah Martin. Actually you are right but the point is i want to delineate a watershed for that river in red line. I overlayed it on the streams generated to help track the pattern on the streams. The issue is that the river flows through two different neighboring regions (i.e. from the top to down of the river overlayed).

Comment: Actually you are right. The issue is that the river flows through two different neighboring regions (top-down direction of the river) but the point is i want to delineate a watershed for that red line. I extracted the red line file from CAD (.dxf format) where the line somehow comprised of bridges and roads and water, looking at the attribute table. I intentionally overlayed it on the streams generated to help track the flow path patterns on the streams. if there are gaps between two streams where the line passes, is there a way to link it

Comment: Yes, apparently your DEM does not contain enough elevation data to capture the river. This could be due to too low resolution, or other things. If you use ArcHydro you should run the DEM reconditioning tool to burn down your river in the DEM, hence forcing the water to follow that path. However, a contributing factor could also be that you have a too small area for your DEM, and therefore not capturing the full extent of the catchment areas.

Comment: And no, you can't really (logically) link the areas and/or flow paths, since these are derived from your DEM. The way to go is to manipulate the DEM, and here is where bridges and culverts come in to play. Identify those and remove, try if you get other flow paths after that.

Comment: Many thanks Martin. Will try that and update on any issues that will pop up. Gratitude once again